# sql query search for vertical saving

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I need to get all the booktypes which has salesyear only in 2013,2014 and should not have sales in any other year. So in my example data, should only return 'nonfiction'.

I have tried

```
select booktype where salesyear in (2013,2014)
```

this is returning both fiction and nonfiction, but I need to get the data if the salesyear has only in 2013, 2014 but not in any other year

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT booktype
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY booktype
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN salesyear = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND   -- 2013 present
       SUM(CASE WHEN salesyear = 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND   -- 2014 present
       SUM(CASE WHEN salesyear IN (2013, 2014) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)   -- only 2013 and
                                                                               -- only 2014
```

Comment: this gives the booktypes which have sales year 2011 also, which doesn't work. I only need the booktypes must have both  salesyear 2013 and 2014 only

Comment: still gives me the result if the salesyear is only 2013 but my resultset should have both 2013 and 2014

Comment: No it doesn't, reload the page, I added logic to prevent this from happening.

Comment: perfect, Thank you

Comment: I havent downvote... I dont even know how to do that. Can you please let me know what should I do

Answer (score 0):

You may want to get all `BookType` with sales in 2013 and 2014, excluding sales in any year other than 2013 / 2014.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.BookType
FROM MyTable a 
JOIN MyTable b on a.BookType = b.BookType AND b.SalesYear = 2014
WHERE a.SalesYear = 2013
AND a.BookType NOT IN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT BookType
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE SalesYear NOT IN (2013, 2014)
)
```

Comment: this gives me the result set which might be in 2013 or 2014, but the booktypes should be in both 2013 and 2014

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware it's looking up on both 2013 and 2014. I've modified the query. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will satisfy your requirement above:

```
SELECT s.BookType 
FROM Test s
WHERE SalesYear IN (2013,2014)
AND NOT EXISTS(
SELECT BookType 
FROM Test 
WHERE BookType = s.BookType AND SalesYear NOT IN (2013,2014))
GROUP BY BookType HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(SalesYear)) > 1
```